# Cannot connect containers with database and app in network

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to create a simple network from 2 containers: with app and with postgres database. And I'm facing a problem: application cannot get access to db. I saw docs and google examples, it seems to me that I did everything how it described in docker docs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) but, obviously it's wrong. I'll be very grateful for any explanation of the causes of this error. So,

my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  network_name:
    name: network_name
    driver: bridge


services:
  src:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=data
      - USER=user_name
      - PASSWORD=some_password
      - DB_NAME=database_name
      - PG_PORT=5432

    volumes:
      - /home/user/project/src

    ports:
      - 8011:8011

    expose:
      - "8011"

    depends_on:
      - data

    links:
      - data

    networks:
      - network_name

  data:
    image:
      postgres

    env_file:
      ./data/words_db.env

    restart: always


    volumes:
      - /home/user/project/data

    ports:
      - ${PG_PORT:-5432}:5432
    expose:
      - "5432"


    build: ./data

    networks:
      - network_name
```

src Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch

RUN mkdir ./src
COPY  . ./src
#COPY ../vocabs ./src
RUN cd ./src && ls && pwd
WORKDIR ./src

RUN pip install transformers==4.2.2
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
RUN pip install pymorphy2==0.9.1
RUN pip install starlette==0.13.6
RUN pip install uvicorn==0.13.1
RUN pip install fastapi==0.62.0

RUN export PATH=$PATH:/home/kvelichko/Projects/emoticon_rus_prod_server/src/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python:/usr/bin/python3.8:/usr/bin/python:/usr/bin/python

EXPOSE 8011

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "api.py"]
```

get_db_config function (calls by api.py from project/src):

```
def get_db_config():

    config = {"database": os.environ["DB_NAME"],
              "user": os.environ["USER"],
              "password": os.environ["PASSWORD"],
              "host": os.environ["POSTGRES_HOST"],
              "port": os.environ["PG_PORT"]
              }

    return config
```

And than I try to use psycopg2 lib for build my database inside a container with app:

```
 with psycopg2.connect(**config) as connection:
    ...
```

But my app can't get access to db.

Traceback:

```
src_1   | ERROR:uvicorn.error:Exception in ASGI application
src_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 394, in run_asgi
src_1   |     result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
src_1   |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 190, in __call__
src_1   |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
src_1   |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
src_1   |     raise exc from None
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
src_1   |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
src_1   |     raise exc from None
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
src_1   |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
src_1   |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
src_1   |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
src_1   |     response = await func(request)
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 188, in app
src_1   |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 135, in run_endpoint_function
src_1   |     return await dependant.call(**values)
src_1   |   File "api.py", line 38, in get_predict
src_1   |     sentence, subj = get_custom_objects(input_sent, is_subj=True)
src_1   |   File "/workspace/src/checks.py", line 25, in get_custom_objects
src_1   |     subject = Word(analyzer.parse(words[-1])[0].normal_form, verbose=verbose)
src_1   |   File "/workspace/src/custom_classes.py", line 35, in __init__
src_1   |     self.info = self._get_info(original_word=self.as_is,
src_1   |   File "/workspace/src/custom_classes.py", line 127, in _get_info
src_1   |     _word_is_in_db_already = check_word(word=original_word,
src_1   |   File "/workspace/src/implement_postgres.py", line 204, in check_word
src_1   |     with psycopg2.connect(**config) as connection:
src_1   |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
src_1   |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
src_1   | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "data" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

Thank you an advance for any clarification!

upd: I tried also set POSTGRES_HOST=postgres://data but with the same result.

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete setting from first-generation Docker networking.  It probably shouldn't cause any trouble here, but does removing it help?  Is the database container actually starting up (the `image: postgres` but also `build: ./data` suggests you may not be running what you think)?

Comment: Thank you, I've romoved "links" and "build", but still facing the same issues..